# Bourne: How to preserve a string in a variable?

Tags: string, sh

I'm trying to execute the following line in Bourne:

LIST="-foo, -bar, baz"

However, I am getting an error:

-bar: command not found

Can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: Works for me (tm). Whose Bourne shell implementation are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to do this in Autoconf

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the string is in fact not quoted.

Any chance you are doing `LIST=$somevariable` instead of what you wrote in the question? Because then you should write `LIST="$somevariable"` instead.